Gauge theory of Electomagnetic Potentials - 2nd order derivatives
A quick introduction: In literature of electromagnetic theory, I saw little to no limitation on the formulating of an arbitrary gauge to the potential functions $(\phi,\vec{A})$. Perhaps it's required (yet I never saw this being formulated properly) that the gauge condition should be formulated as
$X(\phi)+Y(\vec{A})=0$
with the functions X() and Y() being linear, e.g. $X(a\phi_1+b\phi_2)=aX(\phi_1)+bX(\phi_2)$.
Then, if two gauge-pairs $(\phi_1,\vec{A}_1)$ and $(\phi_2,\vec{A}_2)$ that are related using some gauge-function $\psi$ such that
$\phi_2=\phi_1-\partial_t\psi$
$\vec{A}_2=\vec{A}_1+\nabla\psi$
The two gauge-pairs are part of the same gauge-family if
$Y(\nabla\psi)-X(\partial_t\psi)=0$
My question is as follows:
When discussing gauge selections - I've only seen the Lorenz gauge or the Coulomb gauge. In both cases, it's the gauge is set by taking 1st-order derivatives of the gauge functions.
Assuming gauge condition formulated as above, is it also a limitation that $X(\phi)$ and $Y(\vec{A})$ can include up to 1st-order derivatives, or can they have 2nd-order derivatives?
Are there any repercussions for such a gauge constraint?
(I often read that EM theory and General Relativity have many parallels between them in formulation, and I know that in GR one can "select the coordinates" using a harmonic condition, yet despite its name - the constraint equations include only 1st order derivatives of the metric-tensor)

The Gauge fixing condition must be (1) accessible (This is addressed in Gabriel's answer), and (2) it must uniquely fix the gauge. In E&M one way to see that you get the gauge degree of freedom is that the Legendre transformation from the Lagrangian to the Hamiltonian is not surjective. Starting with the Lagrangian,
$$ L = -\int d^3x \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} $$
In taking the Legendre transform we find two constraints $C_1 = \Pi^0 = 0$ and $C_2 = \nabla\cdot\mathbf{\Pi} = 0$. This means the dynamics take place on a "surface" that is a subset of our phase space (the space of functions $ (A_\mu(x),\Pi^\mu(x))$). These constraints are first class constraints ({C_1,C_2} = 0) which means that the poison bracket restricted to this surface is degenerate, thus there are directions on the constraint surface where the time dynamics aren't uniquely defined, so we have gauge orbits along these directions.
Now, we can fix the gauge by picking other constraints that define a surface that intersects our constraint surface at a unique point on each gauge orbit. These constraints should be chosen so that they have non-vanishing Poisson brackets with our first-class constraints. For E&M we could for example choose $C_3 = A^0 = 0$ and $C_4 = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0 $, this turns our first class constraints and our gauge fixing constraints into second class constraints which can be dealt with using the Dirac Bracket which is just the Poisson bracket restricted to our now further constrained surface.
Again for this to work the gauge fixing surface must intersect the constraint surface at one point along every gauge orbit, which is equivalent to the conditions I gave at the beginning. Sometimes the topology of the gauge orbits makes this difficult to do (at least globally). For example, in nonabelian gauge theory you can't use the Coulomb gauge globally because of the Gribov Ambiguity. Sometimes certain gauge conditions only partially fix a gauge. For example, the Lorenz gauge in E&M $\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0$ has a residual gauge freedom where you can shift by a gauge transformation $A_\mu \mapsto A_\mu + \partial_\mu \lambda$ where $\Box\lambda= 0$. This is usually dealt with by fixing boundary conditions. A good resource for this sort of stuff is the first chapter of Quantization of Gauge Systems by Henneaux and Teitolbom.
Going back to your original question. There is nothing specifically (that I know of) that precludes using second-order derivatives or nonlinear gauge fixing constraints.

This is only a partial answer to your question.
What you say about X and Y being linear is not necessarily true, as I have seen other guage choices like the Weul gauge, $A_t=0$, used in QFT, or the Dirac Gauge $A_\mu A^\mu = k^2$ (which use I don't know).
A gauge choice is valid if it is possible to go from any generic potential $A^{bad}_\mu$, to a potential $A^{good}_\mu = A^{bad}_\mu + \partial_\mu\lambda $ that obeys the gauge choice through a gauge transformation $\lambda$. The particular gauge fixing will impose a condition on $\lambda$ which might, or might not be always possible to fulfill.
